# How to resize column width in Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This how the grid is displayed:
[image]

After clicking column name I am adding arrow for sorting in the column header. So for that, I want to resize my column width.

Note: I am adding the column name and data from the database dynamically. There are two different tables for both of them.

This is code for RegisterMastergrid:

```
    function () {
        debugger;

        $("#Mastergrid").kendoGrid({
            height:550,
            sortable: false,
            reorderable: true,
            scrollable: true,
            selectable: "row",
            resizable: true,
            editable: false,
            autoFitColumn: true,
            Autosize : true ,
            pageable: {
                pageSizes: [10, 15, 20, 25],
                pageSize: 10
            },             
            change: function (e) {
                debugger;
                MasterObject._selectedRow = this.select().closest("tr").children("td");
            }
        });
        function onDataBound() {
            var grid = $("#Mastergrid").data("kendoGrid");
            for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
                grid.autoFitColumn(i);
            }

        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/select-columns-in-kendo-grid), there is no event for selecting the column head, so instead, you can bind your own click event on the column heads like this:

```
$('table thead tr th').click(function(ele){
    console.log(this);
    this.style.width = "200px";
});
```

You can bind this when you are done initializing the grid :)

Comment: But by default I am adding that sort symbol for one column and I want to increase size of that column as well !

Comment: I don‘t really understand what you mean, do you want the column to be another size on init or do you want it bound to the click event?